# Sending 240x240px image in websocket to other clients in less than 100ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

In a project I am making, I need to send images very quickly, however with socket.io, the images send at a low frame-rate, I re-implemented the code to use the native WebSocket library both in client and server but that doesn't give that much performance gain. Right now I am sending an array of pixals. Is there a way to compress this data in client-side javascript, or even better, any tips to speed up WebSockets?

Here is the client-side code for sending the image:

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasDimension, canvasDimension);

                      const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasDimension, canvasDimension);
                      const buffer = [...new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.data.buffer)];
                      
                      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                        type: "webcamSnapshot",
                        payload: buffer
                      }));
```

Comment: Why are you converting binary data to JSON before sending it?  Why not just send the image bytes directly as binary and let the client deal with it?

Comment: @selbie WebSockets require string data as far as I know.

Comment: That would be incorrect.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#sending-binary-data

Comment: I think I might need to have multiple webSocket servers for each type of message, then I can only send the data, and not have to send in string format. (right now I am using the same socket for different types of messages so I have to have a type property)

Comment: First measure your performance now.  It's entirely possible that my speculation that stringifying binary data into json isn't the culprit of your performance issue.  You mention "low frame rate". It's going to be really hard to send uncompressed RGB bytes over the wire at any smooth frame rate.  240x240 at 1fps is already  1.3 megabit/sec.  But again, maybe the performance is on the receive side, not the send side.  Measure where the issue is occurring first before throwing code at the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could send a (compressed) image rather than RGB bytes?  Using [canvas.toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)